# Struggling with making a sql query

Tags: sql

I've been struggling with making a sql query that returns the following ;

A list of names of all pairs who are coworkers and friends

my table is build from the following command;

```
CREATE TABLE relation(
name_1 varchar(255),
name_2 varchar(255),
rel varchar(255)
)
```

I've tried

```
SELECT NAME_1, NAME_2 from relation
where rel LIKE 'c%' and rel like 'f%';
```

but the table returned is empty.

Comment: it will be better if you post the data of your table .  i think your table is not completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No row can have a `rel` that starts with `c` and `f` at once.

One approach would be to create a subquery to classify relations.  Here, it classifies coworkers as 1 and friends as 2.  To detect relation rows with the names swapped, the query picks the first name in alphabetical order as `name_1`.  The `having` clause demands that both types of relations are present.

```
select  name_1
,       name_2
from    (
        select  case when name_1 > name_2 then name_1 else name_2 end as name_1
        ,       case when name_1 > name_2 then name_2 else name_1 end as name_2
        ,       case when rel like 'c%' then 1 
                     when rel like 'f%' then 2 
                end as Type
        from    YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
group by
        name_1
,       name_2
having  count(distinct Type) = 2
```

Another approach is to select all coworkers, and use `exists` to demand that they are friends too:

```
select  distinct
        case when name_1 > name_2 then name_1 else name_2 end as name_1
,       case when name_1 > name_2 then name_2 else name_1 end as name_2
from    YourTable c
where   c.rel like 'c%'
        and exists
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable f
        where   f.rel like 'f%'
                and 
                (
                    (c.name_1 = f.name_1 and c.name_2 = f.name_2)
                    or (c.name_1 = f.name_2 and c.name_2 = f.name_1)
                )
        )
```

Comment: @user493417: Seems to work for me, see this [data explorer example](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/94569/)

Comment: @user493417: You could try the `case` sorting trick, added to answer

Comment: @user493417: You can probably do that by adding nested `exist` clauses; see if you can figure it out yourself!

Comment: @user493417: Try a nested exist, like `select * from tbl where exists (select * from tbl where exists (select ...`.  Or ask a new question :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
SELECT NAME_1, NAME_2 from relation
where rel LIKE 'c%' or rel like 'f%';
```

rel cannot start with c and start with f.

Answer (score 0):

this condition never exist

```
 rel LIKE 'c%' and rel like 'f%';
```

you cant have word that start with c ***and*** with f !

maybe you mean to **`OR`**

Comment: The table supports the query where two people both are friends and coworkers. Ive tried with WHERE rel = 'friends' and rel = 'coworker'
aswell

Comment: In this situation what will be in db in rel column?

Comment: see @andomar answer, i think it what u looking

Answer (score 0):

> LIKE 'c%' and rel like 'f%';

Think about what you are saying there: return all rows where the column `rel` starts with a c and **at the same time** starts with a f.

Clearly not possible

You probably want:

`where rel LIKE 'c%' OR rel like 'f%'`